# Is there a system call function whose definition calls another system call function?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

In Linux, is there a system call function whose definition calls another system call function?

Or are **all** the system call functions exclusive to each other in the sense that any system call function doesn't call another system call function?

Or are the system call functions **mostly** exlusive to each other in the above sense?

Thanks.

Comment: System calls can't call other system calls because it wouldn't make sense to go through all the effort of doing a system call when you're already in the kernel. There are system call that do a superset of what another system call does like for example dup3 does the same as dup2 plus some more and internally they probably mostly use the same code. Not really sure I understand what you are actually asking though.

Answer (score 5):

As an example, let's examine how the C function [`write()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) is implemented in Linux.

The C library implementation is essentially:

```
ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count)
{
    long retval;

    retval = syscall(__NR_write, fd, buf, count);
    if (retval < 0) {
        errno = -retval;
        return -1;
    } else
        return retval;
}
```

The `syscall()` function is specific to each hardware architecture, operating system, and kernel. It is usually written in assembler. It loads the parameters to specific registers (according to the kernel calling conventions used), and calls into the kernel.

At that point, a security boundary is crossed, and the execution moves to kernel space.

The `write()` syscall implementation in-kernel itself uses the calling process' file description table, to look up a set of file operations specific to that file or socket; the exact code path depends on whether the file descriptor is a file (and in that case, the filesystem it resides on), a pipe, a socket, a character device, or a block device.

Almost all syscalls return a nonnegative value for success, and a negative errno code for error.

In the Linux kernel, it is rare for a syscall implementation to call another function that implements a syscall. Instead, the common parts are factored to kernel-internal functions that both syscall implementation functions call. This makes maintenance easier.

If we look at how the Linux kernel implements the [`faccessat()`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/open.c) and [`access()`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/open.c) syscalls, we see that both simply call the kernel-internal function `do_faccessat()`.

Answer (score 4):

Well, for each system call, only ONE trap is generated, but some calls share codes, for instance, `sys_epoll_create()`, once in kernel mode, calls `sys_epoll_create1()` (see [eventpoll.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.35/source/fs/eventpoll.c#L1215) for kernell 2.6.35):

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(epoll_create, int, size)
{
    if (size <= 0)
        return -EINVAL;

    return sys_epoll_create1(0);
}
```

In more recent kernelk (4.17-rc2), the same functions [share code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17-rc2/source/fs/eventpoll.c#L1982):

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(epoll_create1, int, flags)
{
    return do_epoll_create(flags);
}

SYSCALL_DEFINE1(epoll_create, int, size)
{
    if (size <= 0)
        return -EINVAL;

    return do_epoll_create(0);
}
```

So the answer to your question is yes, but it depends of kernel version...

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your definition of system call.

I'm unaware of any system call traps that, once they enter the kernel, intentionally cause another system call trap to be made.

But the implementation of some system calls - the `sys_xxx` functions in the kernel - can wind up using the implementation of some other system call.

One example of this is [creat](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/open.c#L1110), which does nothing except call the `sys_open` function - the implementation of the `open` system call - with some specific arguments:

```
/*
 * For backward compatibility?  Maybe this should be moved
 * into arch/i386 instead?
 */
SYSCALL_DEFINE2(creat, const char __user *, pathname, umode_t, mode)
{
    return sys_open(pathname, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, mode);
}
```